# Does Google App Engine Support JAVA Proxy API's?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a question surrounding the REST service. I have an application written in C# , i want to put this application onto the cloud. I have a small problem, My Application has a built in C# API. I want to interact with my application and Google app engine. I want to develop a JAVA PROXY on top of GAE so that it can interact with my application using REST protocol and performs CRUD operations on Cloud and returns back data to my application.

Is it possible to do this ? to what i know is that SANDBOX feature doesn't allow us to directly interact with the App Engine.

Any suggestion on this.........

Thanks Heaps

Suraj

Answer (score 1):

You don't need [`Java Proxy API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) in order to make http requests to another server (I guess you did not have java's `Proxy` class in mind?).

Yes, AppEngine can make HTTP/REST requests to other servers via [URL Fetch java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html).